# Facebook notifications are shown multiple times

Tags: macos, notifications, facebook

Whenever I get a new Facebook notification, the same message is displayed 20 times in the notification center. I noticed this is only the case for Facebook, and I've been experiencing this since I upgraded to Sierra.

Any ideas on how to solve this, or what might be the cause of this issue?

**Edit:**
There is a [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7709245?start=0&tstart=0) on Apple's discussion forum about this issue. However, not solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [different thread on the official Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7705396?start=0&tstart=0) that claims to have a solution:

1. disable all facebook related notification settings in system settings -> notifications.
2. remove your facebook account from system settings -> internet accounts.
3. remove all facebook related objects from your keychain and restart your mac.
4. log on to facebook, you will be asked if you want to use this account for mac system integration, click on later.
5. in facebook go to settings -> security -> where you're logged in -> delete all old session, especially the ones under "Apple OS Integration".
6. clear safari cache and restart your mac.
7. log on to facebook, you will be asked if you want to use this account for mac system integration, this time click ok and check the notifications setting, if everything ok, restart your mac once again.

Answer (score -5):

One useful method would be to turn off notifications in the settings then turn it back on. If that doesn't work, try rebooting your system too.

**To Reboot The iPhone:**
Hold the power button for a few seconds, then slide at the top to power off. Wait a few seconds then hold the power button for a few seconds to power on the iPhone.

**To Reboot The iMac:**
Click "Restart" in the Apple menu. If that isn't possible, press the iMac power button to power off then press it again to power on.

**To Reboot On Windows:**
Click the Windows icon, then click the short arrow, which will give more options. Click "Restart" to restart the Windows system.

Comment: This is meant for just the Mac... Not for Windows or iPhone!

Comment: I did not know that.